# header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'") gives an error in PHP

Tags: php, content-security-policy

I have tried adding `header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'");` in my php file, but when opening the page I get

> The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered via a  element.

I know it is not supposed to be used in meta tags, but is there another way to use the frame-ancestors or I am not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `header` function is setting a HTTP header and does not create a meta tag. That message says you have a meta tag; it could be possible that you're doing both at the same time, only one of which is valid. **Remove the meta tag; keep the header function.**

Comment: The thing is that I only use the frame-ancestors in this header function, nowhere else. And have in the code ```<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap: wss: ws:;">``` 
but not for that specific page